# order custom posts by custom field [WCK]

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields

I am using WCK to create the custom post type and fields.

I have created a custom post type `athlete` and one of the custom fields for this post type is 'last-name'; I can display all the athlete on my athlete archive page. I would like to sort them by the last name ascending.

I have seen this format show up a few times in answers, but it doesn't seem to work for me, the athletes are still sorted by published date (newest first):

```
<?php query_posts( "post_type=athlete".$query_string."&meta_key=last-name&orderby=meta_value&order=ASC" ); ?>
```

I have also tried this format, with similarly ineffective results:

```
<?php $q=array( 'post_type' => 'athlete',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_key' => 'last-name',
    'orderby'=> 'meta_value',
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($q);
```

Comment: try echo $my_query->request , what query it shows to you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using *meta_value* in the *orderby* clause, you should use *meta_value_num*. This should order your query correctly. See more details on that here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

```
    <?php $q=array( 'post_type' => 'athlete',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'meta_key' => 'last-name',
            'orderby'=> 'meta_value_num',
    );
    $my_query = new WP_Query($q);
```

Comment: Tried that with no luck!

Answer (score 0):

- Under "Custom Fields Creator" switch the toggle button to "Enable Unserialized Fields"
- Resave the existing Custom Post Type pages that contain your sortable field
- use order_by => meta_value, meta_key => customfieldsmetaname_fieldslug_1 **(note the "_1")**

Didn't do this via code but via Switft Templates backend funktionality in WCK v2.1.4. I asked the support how to do it as far as I remember. Could be more intuitive ;-)

Here a screenshot of the radio button you need to change
[image]

Here how the Swift Template query arguments look in my case
[image]

**Update**

Seems there is also a [Custom Query Arguments addon](https://www.cozmoslabs.com/docs/wordpress-creation-kit-documentation/swift-templates/custom-query-arguments/#Custom_Query_Arguments)